# MS CRM - send notification to user (by email or some report), once some related records reach to specific stage of my custom BUSINESS PROCESS FLOW

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have entity "Job" which has child entity "Order" so a Job record can have multiple "Orders".  Every "Order" has custom  approval BUSINESS PROCESS FLOW which has three stages. My requirement is to notify Job owner or Job creator, once all of the Orders  of that Job reaches to final stage of approval BUSINESS PROCESS FLOW. How it needs to be done in MS CRM 2016? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without any custom coding this will not be possible. The closest you can get is to create an "On-Demand" workflow that sends a notification to Job Owner/Creator (this workflow should be running on-demand on Order entity). Now, in your Business Process Flow, on the last stage, simply specify a Workflow as a step. You can define, if it should run when last stage begins or ends. As you already figured out, that would mean that notification will be sent every time an Order is finished.
I think that you can also make use of rollup fields and some recurring workflow checking the value of such fields, but since creating a recurring workflow is not straightforward, I would not go that way.

We are on Stack Overflow, so we should talk about coding solutions :)

If you want only one notification, you should create a Custom Workflow Activity that will run inside that workflow and will simply check for "open" Orders (I don't know what are the proper status values for Orders in your case, but I assume that "open" and "closed" are good enough to exaplain the idea). If there are still open Orders, it should return false, then in your workflow you would check that value end simply stop the workflow without sending notification. If it returns true - then you should send notification.This is how I usually handle this tasks, as Custom Activity is really simple and can be made reusable for different entities.